# jqGrid multiselect columnChooser in IE6 height

Tags: jqgrid, internet-explorer-6

Does anybody knows how to expand the height of the columnChooser in IE6?

It works perfectly fine in IE7 and IE8 but it won't expand to the height of 240 set in the code for IE6. Any post show event or a method $("#colchooser_grid").attr("height",240) that I can call when the window shows up.

oops "I can't show pictures yet"

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`columnChooser` has [options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods#options):

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('columnChooser', options);
```

One from the options is `height`. Try, for example, with

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('columnChooser', {height:300});
```

**UPDATED**: The following code work:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('columnChooser');
setTimeout(function(){
    var d=$("div.ui-dialog[aria-labelledby='ui-dialog-title-colchooser_list']")
    d.height(530);
    $("div#colchooser_list",d[0]).height(400);
    $("div.selected, div.available",d[0]).height(350);
    $("div.selected, div.available","div#colchooser_list").height(350);
});
```

Comment: I need to set the height when columnChooser pops up. The code already have a default height of 240              var d=a('<div id="colchooser_'+g[0].p.id+'" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden"><div><select multiple="multiple"></select></div></div>'),
            e=a("select",d);
            b=a.extend({
               width:420,height:240,classname:null,done:function(f){

Comment: @Fabio: Yes, default value of the height is 240. You wrote that you want "expand the height". I don't understand what the problem is. Is there are bug in IE6 and the hight is don't 240? If you post somewhere the picture I could place it in the text of your question. Could you exactly what is the problem? Is `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('columnChooser', {height:300});` don't change the dialog height?

Comment: Oleg thanks for your reply. Let me explain a little bit better. I want to have the default of 240 just like it shows in the other IE versions. In IE6 it uses the "min-height: 51px" which is set in the css. IE6 is not honoring the height not the default or anyother one that you pass in the constructor to columnChooser.                                                       However I am looking to override the min-height (Which is the one IE6 seem to honor) by setting that value after I call the constructor for columnChooser. So far I got:  $("#colchooser_grid").css("min-height","180px");

Comment: @Fabio: OK, I understand now, but if there are a bug, then you can change the height, but probably in many steps. First if you has grid with id="grid" you can use `$("div.selected, div.available","div#colchooser_grid").height(350);` to expand the size of the column cooser. I have no IE6 so it is difficult for me to reproduce the problem. If you will have problem with changing the dialog height you can try to place the changes in `setTimeout`: `setTimeout(function(){$("div.selected, div.available","div#colchooser_list").height(350);});`

Comment: The only way to fix this will be passing a className because the panel is built in the flight when you click the button however.

Comment: When I create a css class and pass it to IE6 it does not respond either. Mozilla and IE8 take the css. So I revert back to no multiselect and I get the same height of 51px so the error has been there even before multiselect. This probaly can only be fix by changing the code of jqGrid.

Comment: @Fabio: I don't agree with you. In my tests (not in IE6) the code `$("#grid").jqGrid('columnChooser');setTimeout(function(){$("div.selected, div.available","div#colchooser_grid").height(350);});` do change the height of the 'columnChooser'. The user can not see the original height, he sees the column cooser dialog already in the new modified form. Do you tried the code?

Comment: In mine too with all the other browser of course it works. The problem is IE6 it does not.

Comment: @Oleg that does not work because the user clicks in the button on the toolbar and that is when the column chooser panel is built. when you make the call above there is no "div#colchooser_grid" yet so there is no effect.

Comment: @Fabio: I make the call using `"div#colchooser_grid"` **after** the `$("#grid").jqGrid('columnChooser');` which create the dialog. If you have computer with IE6 try click the last button on the navigator toolbar of the demo http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders2.htm and write me whether it work.

Comment: @Fabio: I found IE6 in one old virtual machine. After minimal modification the http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders2.htm do work on IE6.

Comment: @Oleg I got a chance to test your changes. I downloaded your html page and I run it and it works. Then I included your changes in my page and it works. I only needed lines var d=$("div.ui-dialog[aria-labelledby='ui-dialog-title-colchooser_list']"); $("div.selected, div.available",d[0]).height(240); in the setTimeOut function. I believe you deserve credit for your answer. I am not sure if it has been done. If not let me know how to do it. If you will please explain the select inside the brackets "aria-labelledby ...". Thanks

Comment: @Fabio: It is very simple. jqGrid create additionally to well known attributes like "id", "class", "style" and do on some [WAI-ARIA properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAI-ARIA). The div which we need to find has attribute `aria-labelledby='ui-dialog-title-colchooser_list'` So we use jQuery [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). Alternative one could find the same div with `$("#colchooser_list").parent();` see http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders3.htm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js when I went back to 
jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js it all works fine. The right height apperas in the column chooser. 
Now the only problem is when the column chooser is over the tool bar search it breaks the panel and shows the select from beneath. But that is just normal IE6 behavior. Not sure exactly what changed but that is the problem.